# Prove that $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am curious if I am doing this proof correctly. In the instructions, it says to make use of the following, true, statement:
\begin{equation}
(\forall \varepsilon>0 )(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall k \in \mathbb{N})[k \geq N \implies |x_k-x_N|<\varepsilon]
\end{equation}

Proof: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, if $k \geq N$, then $|x_k - x_N| < \varepsilon/2$. Let $k,j > N$. Then $|x_k - x_j| \leq |x_k - x_N| + |x_N - x_j| < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon$.  Thus $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I am confused. Exactly what are you supposed to show? That a sequence is Cauchy? In that case which sequence? Or that the "following, true statement" is indeed the definition of "$x_n$ is Cauchy"?

Comment: All I was given is: Let {xn}∞
n=1 be a sequence. Suppose the following statement about this sequence is true:
(∀ε > 0)(∃N ∈ N)(∀k ∈ N)[k ≥ N =⇒ |xk − xN | < ε]. Prove it is cauchy

Comment: @Arthur Not quite.  The definition of Cauchy is that for all epsilon there is an N so that $n,m > N$ then $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$.   What you are given in this exercise is that for all epsilon there is an N so that $m > N$ then $|a_m - a_N| < \epsilon$.  ie. only the difference between all terms and $a_N$ is small..  Not between any two is small.  They are equivalent statements as the OP proved.

Comment: @fleablood So do you think I sufficiently proved it?

Comment: Yeah, I do.  Well you prove "half way condition" $\implies$ definition of Cauchy.  Which is all you were asked to do.  For fun you could prove definition of Cauchy $\implies$ "half way condition" (it'd be easy).  Then you'd have "half way condition" $\iff$ definition of Cauchy.  And therefore "halfway condition" could be an alternative definition of Cauchy.  But you weren't asked to do that.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What are you trying to prove? Are you trying to prove that any sequence is Cauchy? Are you trying to prove that your statement is equivalent to being Cauchy?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks correct to me. To sum up, you used the fact that $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence and the triangle inequality to show that $(x_n)$ has to satisfy the Cauchy criterion.

To sum up, let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given. Based on the fact about $(x_n)$, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \in \Bbb N$ and $n\ge N \implies \vert x_n - x_N\vert < \epsilon/2$. Let $j$ and $k$ be integers greater than $N$. It follows by the triangle inequality that
$$
\vert x_j - x_k\vert \le \vert x_j - x_N\vert + \vert x_N - x_k\vert \lt \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.
$$
Hence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.